# Generated Source with Macros in a Scala 2.13 and Mill project not found in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala-macros, zio, mill

I use [zio-macros](https://github.com/zio/zio-macros) in a *Scala 2.13* / *Mill* Project.

Here the example:

```
@accessible
@mockable
trait AccountObserver {
  val accountObserver: AccountObserver.Service[Any]
}

object AccountObserver {
  trait Service[R] {
    def processEvent(event: String): ZIO[R, Nothing, Unit]
  }

  // autogenerated `object Service { ... }`
  // autogenerated `object > extends Service[AccountObserver] { ... }`
  // autogenerated `implicit val mockable: Mockable[AccountObserver] = ...`
}
```

I can run the test and it finds the autogenerated code.

The problem is that in *Intellij* references to the autogenerated code do **not** compile.

Do I have to configure something or what is missing?

Answer (score 1):

The following project compiles

*build.sc*

```
import mill._, scalalib._

object root extends ScalaModule {
  def scalaVersion = "2.13.1"
  val zioMacrosV = "0.4.0"
  def ivyDeps = Agg(
    ivy"dev.zio::zio-macros-core:${zioMacrosV}",
    ivy"dev.zio::zio-macros-access:${zioMacrosV}",
    ivy"dev.zio::zio-macros-mock:${zioMacrosV}"
  )
  def scalacOptions = Seq(
    "-Ymacro-annotations",
    "-Ymacro-debug-lite"
  )
}
```

*root/src/App.scala*

```
import zio.ZIO
import zio.macros.access.accessible
import zio.macros.mock.mockable

@accessible
@mockable
trait AccountObserver {
  val accountObserver: AccountObserver.Service[Any]
}

object AccountObserver {
  trait Service[R] {
    def processEvent(event: String): ZIO[R, Nothing, Unit]
  }
}
```

Command `mill root.compile` compiles the project

```
//{
//  abstract trait AccountObserver extends scala.AnyRef {
//    val accountObserver: AccountObserver.Service[Any]
//  };
//  object AccountObserver extends scala.AnyRef {
//    def <init>() = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    };
//    abstract trait Service[R] extends scala.AnyRef {
//      def processEvent(event: String): ZIO[R, Nothing, Unit]
//    };
//    object Service extends scala.AnyRef {
//      def <init>() = {
//        super.<init>();
//        ()
//      };
//      case object processEvent extends _root_.zio.test.mock.Method[String, Unit] with scala.Product with scala.Serializable {
//        def <init>() = {
//          super.<init>();
//          ()
//        }
//      }
//    };
//    implicit val mockable: _root_.zio.test.mock.Mockable[AccountObserver] = ((mock: _root_.zio.test.mock.Mock) => {
//      final class $anon extends AccountObserver {
//        def <init>() = {
//          super.<init>();
//          ()
//        };
//        val accountObserver = {
//          final class $anon extends Service[Any] {
//            def <init>() = {
//              super.<init>();
//              ()
//            };
//            def processEvent(event: String): _root_.zio.IO[Nothing, Unit] = mock(Service.processEvent, event)
//          };
//          new $anon()
//        }
//      };
//      new $anon()
//    });
//    object $greater extends Service[AccountObserver] {
//      def <init>() = {
//        super.<init>();
//        ()
//      };
//      def processEvent(event: String): _root_.zio.IO[Nothing, Unit] = _root_.zio.ZIO.accessM(<empty> match {
//        case (env @ (_: AccountObserver)) => env.accountObserver.processEvent(event)
//      })
//    }
//  };
//  ()
//}
```

Create IntelliJ files

```
mill mill.scalalib.GenIdea/idea
```

and then **open** the project in IntelliJ (do not **import** it).

Now Ctrl+Shift+F9 compiles the project (similarly to above).

You can use for example reference to object `AccountObserver.Service` (this compiles). Surely IntelliJ highlights `Service` in red but this doesn't matter.

Comment: _"Surely IntelliJ highlights Service in red but this doesn't matter."_. But that is exactly the problem it is hard to code if you have compile exception all over in the source code.

Comment: @pme This is not compile exception, this is just wrong highlighting.

Comment: @pme You should get used that IntelliJ sometimes highlights Scala code incorrectly. Macros are too tricky for IntelliJ. This doesn't depend on how you build your project, with sbt or mill.

Comment: But also Code Completion and Code Navigation does not work (same problem with VS Code)

Comment: The red marker _was_ the issue. I fixed that part of the project generator. Either run the latest snapshot of mill or wait for the next mill release > 0.5.2.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:  This answer does not address the issue.

---

This is a bug in the IntelliJ IDEA project generator of mill 0.5.2 and earlier. Mill versions since `0.5.2-9-ea4f04` will contain a fix for that particular issue. (For reference: [#729](https://github.com/lihaoyi/mill/pull/729), [#728](https://github.com/lihaoyi/mill/issues/728))

To work around: Add a `.mill-version` file in your project containing that version number (or any newer, of course) and rerun the IDEA project generator.

```
$ echo -n "0.5.2-9-ea4f04" > .mill-version
$ mill mill.scalalib.GenIdea/idea
```

Comment: This fix did not help. But I also tried it with a sbt project - same problem. Here is the class that compiles but shows errors in intellij: https://github.com/pme123/zio-examples/blob/master/macros/src/pme123/zio/examples/macros/AccessExampleApp.scala

Comment: I can see, that it's not generated _source_ code, so the issue I spoke about in my answer isn't exactly the same, because there are no new files which IntelliJ IDEA needs to take into account.